# Unable to understand motivation behind alternate definition of differentiability

Tags: calculus

I am reading a text (Calculus of several variables by Lang) that is trying to motivate the definition of a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ being differentiable. There is a step I don't understand within this, which we will shortly get to.

To begin we fix $x$, consider a differentiable function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, and let

$$g(h) = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} - f'(x).$$

The text then claims we can write

$$f(x+h) - f(x) = f'(x)h + hg(h).$$

This makes sense when we define $g(0) = 0$, as noted in the text. What follows is the part I don't quite understand. The text says:

> Furthermore, we can replace $h$ by $-h$ if we replace $g$ by $-g$. Thus we have shown that if $f$ is differentiable, there exists a function $g$ such that $$f(x+h) - f(x) = f'(x)h + |h|g(h),$$ $$lim_{h\to 0} g(h) = 0.$$

I don't understand how the absolute value is introduced. I suspect I am not understanding the first sentence well enough (replace stuff by their negation). I'm sorry if this is supposed to be super obvious, I'm just not seeing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
h \, g(h)
= |h| \operatorname{sgn}(h) \, g(h)
= |h| \, G(h)
$$
if you let
$$
G(h) = \operatorname{sgn}(h) \, g(h)
.
$$
So
$$
f(x+h) - f(x)
= f'(x)h + h \, g(h)
= f'(x)h + |h| \, G(h)
$$
where $G(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$.

Comment: @HansLundmarkbut in the OP, the function $g(h)$ didn't got replaced by another function ($G(h)$).

Comment: @Yassir: Yes, it does! The text says “if we replace $g$ by $-g$”, and the notation in my answer is just an attempt to make it clearer what is actually meant by this. Let me put it like this: the final $g$ in the original text is *not* the same as the $g$ that they started with, it's actually the function that I've denoted by $G$.

Comment: so why Lang didn't change the variable for $g$, is it just a typo in the book? @HansLundmark

Comment: @Yassir: How would I know? I'm not psychic. Because he was running out of letters and didn't want to waste one, and expected his readers to understand it anyway, perhaps?